# Not able to set jslink property for a field without FullControl permisson on web (sponline)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, jslink, sharepoint-hosted-app, client-side-rendering

For my SharePoint Hosted App, I set the `jslink` property of the field for customized rendering (`JSOM set_jsLink`). This used to work without having `FullControl` permission on web earlier. However, now this doesn't work with `Manage` permission level.

The Field gets updated and then `executeQueryAsync` success callback is hit but yet jslink value is not changed. And App store doesn't accept an App requiring full control permissions!

Is this a change from Microsoft's side? Any relevant link that explains what is the recommended strategy now? Thanks.

Comment: Exactly the same problem... Did you solve it?

Comment: Not yet. We wrote to a PM in Microsoft Office Dev team recently and described the issue. I will post here if we get any response.

Comment: Hi! Any updates here?

Comment: There is no response so far. I think the problem here is that JSLink script code eventually runs in context of user. So an App with just manage permissions is able to make its code run with potentially higher privileges of the user and thus Microsoft has changed it to require full control permissions. Don't know why there is no clarity around this with respect to App store not allowing Full Control Apps.

Comment: https://www.scnsoft.com/blog/pitfalls-of-using-jslink-with-sharepoint-apps-for-office-store I think this can help

Comment: May you share the code using which you set JSLink property, https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/221838/set-jslink-property-of-lists-newform-aspx-from-add-in-using-jsom

Comment: @codemirror Blog concludes that it is not possible to set JSLink from the app, so the problem still remains. As such the blog has good info on the topic so thanks for sharing. We are using very standard JSOM code to set the JSLink on the list field/web part.

Comment: Please refer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/combining-store-add-ins-with-high-trust-permissions/

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are trying to set the `JSLink` for a host web field. If this is the case, you now need **Full Control** permissions, which is not allowed for an Add-In published in the **store**. The new *SharePoint Framework* model will allow full permissions on the DOM because it will no longer be an iframe on an isolated domain.

Until *SharePoint Framework* is released, I suggest you go the one page app approach and use something like React JS or Angular JS to build the whole app. Steep learning curve, but definitely worth it. If you only need to customize a field and use all other SharePoint views and forms, then publishing your customizations as an **AddIn Package** and installing that in the **App Catalog** will allow you to get *Full Control* permissions.